# N#~~~JLPT Level Names

Tags: jlpt

This has been on my mind for a while with nowhere to really ask it. What does the "N" in the JLPT levels (such as N1-N5) stand for? My current theory is [能力]{のうりょく} since these denote the level of skill one possesses, but I'm not certain. This isn't really a burning question either; I just like knowing weird facts like this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about the Japanese language.

Comment: I wasn't sure if this would get flagged or not because it's not completely about Japanese, but I figured it was related enough. I'll keep that in mind for next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In their [新しい「日本語能力試験」ガイドブック概要版](https://www.jlpt.jp/reference/pdf/guidebook_s_j.pdf) they say:

> 「N」は「Nihongo（[日本語]{にほんご}）」、「New（[新]{あたら}しい）」を[表]{あらわ}します。

Comment: 「New」 って、ホンマかいな・・・。「認定」か「能力」かと思ったけど・・・。

Comment: 2010年まで「N」がなかったんです。

Comment: あぁ、そうなんですか～なるほどね～